# How do I "add some context to explain the code sections"?

Tags: support, code-formatting, error-message

How do I format text here? I keep getting this message:

> - Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).

Comment: You cannot create a question exclusively with code.

Answer (score 4):

The message you are receiving is because the question you are trying to post contains just code, which would mean:

- You really posted only code, without a line to explain what you are trying to achieve, why it doesn't work, and which error messages you eventually got.
- You didn't post just code, but you kept adding four spaces at the beginning of every line, which are used in Markdown to format code.

In the first case, you need to add an explanation to your question; in the second case, you need to remove the spaces at the beginning of the lines, if what you wrote is not code.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [the documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Sad, because [this page is the top result on Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=Please+add+some+context+to+explain+the+code+sections)